# Does eclipse comes with complete inbuilt tomcat server?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, eclipse-plugin

I know the question might seems silly to you and can be googled easily. The reason to ask this question is i have bit confusion. Does eclipse comes with complete inbuilt tomcat server or if it so then how can we verify the tomcat version and java version it is using.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

No, Eclipse doesn't have Tomcat server in place, but you can easily add it. There are plenty tutorials how to install and configure it, like: [Creating a Tomcat server](https://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.server.ui.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftomcat.html), [Adding the Apache Tomcat runtimes](https://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.server.ui.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftwtomprf.html), [javatutorial.net](https://javatutorial.net/run-tomcat-from-eclipse)...

Answer (score 0):

No, eclipse cannot come with inbuilt tomcat. You have to select the appropriate  tomcat version on eclipse and browse the apache tomcat server zip file in order to start it.

Follow these steps to configure tomcat

1.If you do not have Apache Tomcat on your machine, you will first need to download and unzipApache Tomcat(this scenario was written using Apache Tomcat version 5.0.28, but other versions can be substituted).
2.Start the Eclipse WTP workbench.3.OpenWindow -> Preferences -> Server -> Installed Runtimesto create a Tomcat installed runtime.
4.Click onAdd...to open theNew Server Runtimedialog, then select your runtime underApache.
5.ClickNext, and fill in yourTomcat installation directory.

6.Ensure the selectedJREis a full JDK and is of a version that will satisfy Apache Tomcat (thisscenario was written using SUN JDK 1.4.2_06).If necessary, you can click onInstalled JREs...to add JDKs to Eclipse.
7.ClickFinish.